# Adding an image to a string with Android SDK

Tags: android, xml, sdk

I am a super newbie to Android Development and wanted to start slow with an Icon Theme for 3rd party launchers. I was wondering if there is any way to add an image (from inside my "drawable" folder) to a string inside "strings.xml"

This is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme properties -->
    <bool name="enableIconPack">true</bool>
    <bool name="enableDockPack">false</bool>

    <string name="authorName">Clay Cauley</string>
    <string name="developerName">Clay Cauley</string>
    <string name="authorLink">MY SITE</string>
    <string name="theme_title">MY TITLE</string>
    <string name="theme_description">This is some text explaining who created the theme and why, etc ... This is also where I would like my logo to appear.</string>
</resources>
```

My problem lies in the last string, "theme_description" --- If it's possible I wanted to get my logo in there so people see it when on this screen:

[image: Screen Shot]

Hopefully wanting to get it where the "Hey" currently is.

I've tried 2-3 different approaches but they were all guesses and none worked so I thought I would try here. Any help is greatly appreciated, even if it's telling me it isn't possible :)

This is my "main.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="65dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:listSelector="#000000"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="-1dp" >
</GridView>
```

Thanks!

Comment: A strange request. Why wouldn't you just use the image in your drawable folder. What is your reasoning behind wanting to convert it to a string. If you really want to do this, you can Base64Encode the image and store it in your strings.xml

Comment: I don't _think_ I want to convert it to a string, I just want it inside that string so it is displayed when the user in on the description of the theme.

Comment: An image converted and stored as a string is never going to be displayed anywhere unless the app that uses it is expecting this kind of formatting and is capable of reading the striung and converting it back to an image.

Comment: So inside "theme_description" I can't use anything such as `<item drawable="logo" />` to pull the image on to that screen?

Comment: You can but as I said, the app that reads the string is going to need to know how to convert it to the required image or format. strings.xml is for strings not images.

Comment: It sounds like you would be better suited storing XML files in the xml resource folder. Try this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is to add an image to a TextView.  There are attributes for that: "android:drawableLeft", "android:drawableRight", "android:drawableStart", etc.

```
<TextView android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_drawable" .../>
```

If you want to define it in a resource file, then do it in styles.xml:

```
<style name="my_text_view_with_drawable">
    <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/my_drawable</item>
</style>

<TextView style="@style/my_text_view_with_drawable" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the original poster https://stackoverflow.com/users/1344453/clay-cauley is asking how would you specify an image to be inserted along with the text from a string in string.xml
Since you can specify links and email inside a string, it would be nice to reference a drawable.
Asked differently how would you do something a la html img tag, something like this :)

```
 <img src="@drawable/icon" >
```

I too am interested in this possibility.
I know how to dedicate the layout with an ImageView and load a bitmap of choice via code.
I think the problem is trying to use TextView (it probably is not designed to display images,  how about if the layout has a WebView control?  Could a string resource reference a bitmap in the drawables, in local storage?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You do this with a kind of layout, like linearlayout or relativelayout.

Comment: Your answer is in the currient Form not helpful at all.

Comment: Why not? he want a layout with an image and same text near, perhaps i misunderstood?